# How to filter the OTU by counts with AWK?

Tags: awk

I am trying to filter all the singleton from a fasta file. 
Here is my input file:

```
 >OTU1;size=3;
 ATTCCCCGGGGGGG 
 >OTU2;size=1;
 ATCCGGGACTGATC
 >OTU3;size=5;
 GAACTATCGGGTAA
 >OTU4;size=1;
 AATTGGCCATCT
```

The expected output is:

```
>OTU1;size=3;
ATTCCCCGGGGGGG 
>OTU3;size=5;
GAACTATCGGGTAA
```

I've tried

```
awk -F'>' '{if($1>=2) {print $0}' input.fasta > ouput.fasta
```

but this will remove all the header for each OTU.

Anyone could help me out?

Comment: What are you trying to filter. You mention counts, but counts of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[=;]' '/^>/{flag=""} $3>=3{flag=1} flag'   Input_file
```

Comment: what does "flag" mean in here?

Comment: @Helen, it is a variable, which I making it TRUE whenever 3rd field of a line is greater or equal to 3.

Comment: We've discussed this a couple of times previously - naming a flag variable `flag` is like naming an integer variable `integer`. Technically correct I suppose but not nearly as useful for readability as naming the variable for what it logically represents such as `count` or `sum` or `total` or `index` or something else and a headach if/when you have 2 integers and name one `integer`. In the case of a flag variable, it's often meant to represent that something was `found` in the input which in small scripts is often then abbreviated to `f` (NOTE: **f** stands for **f**ound, not for **f**lag)

Comment: shouldn't it be `$3>=2`, or better `$3>1`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '/>/{f=/=1;/}!f' file
 >OTU1;size=3;
 ATTCCCCGGGGGGG
 >OTU3;size=5;
 GAACTATCGGGTAA
```

Comment: smart, concise and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v FS='[;=]' 'prev_sz>=2 && !/size/{print prev RS $0}   /size/{prev=$0;prev_sz=$(NF-1)}'

>OTU1;size=3;
 ATTCCCCGGGGGGG
 >OTU3;size=5;
 GAACTATCGGGTAA
```

Store the size from each line in `prev_sz` variable and whole line in `prev` variables. Now check if its `>= 2`, then print the previous line and the current line. `RS` is used to print new line.

Answer (score 0):

While all the above methods work, they are limited to the fact that input always has to look the same. I.e the sequence-name in your fasta-file needs to have the form:

```
>NAME;size=value;
```

A few solutions can handle a bit more extended sequence-names, but none handle the case where things go a bit more generic, i.e.

```
>NAME;label1=value1;label2=value2;STRING;label3=value3;
```

**Print sequence where label `xxx` matches value `vvv`**:

```
awk '/>{f = /;xxx=vvv;/}f' file.fasta
```

**Print sequence where label `xxx` has a numeric value `p` bigger than `q`**:

```
awk -v label="xxx" -v limit=q \
    'BEGIN{ere=";" label "="}
     />/{ f=0; match($0,ere);value=0+substr($0,RSTART+length(ere)); f=(value>limit)}
     f' <file>
```

In the above `ere` is a regular expression we try to match. We use it to find the location of the value attached to label `xxx`. This substring will have none-numeric characters after its value, but by adding 0 to it, it is converted to a number, losing all non-numeric values (i.e. `3;label4=value4;` is converted to `3`). We check if the value is bigger than our limit, and print the sequence based on that result.